# Is using Celery for task management in cluster good idea?

Tags: python, cloud, celery, distributed-computing

I'm going to use Celery to manage tasks in cluster. There will be one master server and some worker servers. Master sends tasks to the worker servers (any number) and gets the result. Task state should be trackable. Backend is RabbitMQ.
Is using Celery in this case a good Idea? Or are there better solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMHO It's a very good idea. I have used it few times in Amazon EC2 in this manner and it was great each time.

One of the big advantages is that it can handle failure of worker servers, so the dynamic nature of the infrastructure is not a problem and you still get things done.

I'm sorry that this answer is so brief, but I believe it answers OPs question. There's not much more to it. Celery is great, does the job, has good docs. Go with it :)